# Advected Dirac comb with random number of teeth which are born and die

Tags: statistical-mechanics, stochastic-processes, quantum-transport

I'm looking for a topic which I struggle to put into words. It's a reasonable consideration which I expect has been carefully studied. I hope someone can tell me the name of it and offer some guidance about where I can read about it.

Consider there are a random number of $n(t)$
points which are subject to a Markov birth-death scheme. 
Each point is characterized by its time of birth $\tau_s$ and its place of birth $x_s$. All points advect with velocity $u$ until they die, so their density is 
$$\gamma(x,t) = \sum_{s=0}^{n(t)}\delta(x-x_s - u(t-\tau_s))$$

I would like to learn to develop such a stochastic model so I can study its statistical properties. An example would be the mean number of active particles $\langle \gamma(x,t) \rangle$ or the mean flux of particles past a point $x_0$:

$$ \langle q(x_0,t) \rangle  = u\langle \gamma(x_0,t) \rangle $$

Does anyone know of a model like this? 
The closest thing I have found is the birth death immigration emigration process from Cox and Miller (1965) or Gardiner (1983).

Is there a context in stochastic physics where such a 'random advected dirac comb' emerges? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In a frame moving with velocity $u$, won't you get that all particles are stationary? Then you get the birth-death statistics in the original (advected) positions. In other words, if you define $y = x+ut$, then $\gamma(y,t) = \sum_{s=0}^{n(t)}\delta(y-y_s)$.